# Unable to write on List. Tried multiple methods

Tags: r

I am writing a code in which I am trying to create a "list" vector using for loop. I have solved most of the code except ONE small problem.

Here is my code:

```
dnt_1 = vector("list", length(unique(dnt$A)))
dnt_2 = vector("list", length(unique(dnt$A))) #length = 22
dnt_3 = NULL
dnt_4 = NULL
for (i in unique(dnt$PLAZA)){
     dnt_3 = subset(dnt, A == i)
     dnt_4 = subset(dnt_3, select = c("B", "C", "D"))
     dnt_1[[i]] = dnt_3
     dnt_2[[i]] = dnt_4
     }
```

dnt_1 list is coming out perfectly. 
The list: dnt_2 also shows NULL value. The result shows 22 values are NULL and rest 22 as the subset variable. Basically, the first 22 values are of no use.

Someone please help me to improve that error. Would be of great help if someone can also attach a document or explain how to rectify such errors in general.

Comment: In the first iteration, `dnt_1` is `NULL`  May be you need to change the order of `dnt_1[[i]] <- dnt_3` before the `dnt_4 = subset(`

Comment: @akrun Can you please explain how to rectify that?

Comment: Try `for (i in unique(dnt$PLAZA)){dnt_3 = subset(dnt, A == i);dnt_1[[i]] = dnt_3;dnt_4 = subset(dnt_1, select = c("B", "C", "D")); dnt_2[[i]] = dnt_4
     }`

Comment: I made a small edit to my code. dnt_4 = subset(dnt_3..).

Comment: Now do you have the same issue

Comment: Yes, I do. Now even dnt_1 has first 22 elements as NULL and the rest are subset result.

Comment: Well, not sure if its the right method but when I changed the first command to dnt_1= list(), the results are coming just fine. @akrun

Comment: Yes, you are assigning it to `NULL`, so each time it is removed